# ngrx-store strictStateImmutability does not prevent state from being replaced

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I'm going to do my best to explain this question. With strictStateImmutability you are not allowed to modify a property of state directly like this.

```
export const reducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(addTodo, (state, { todo }) => {
    // Violation 1: we assign a new value to `todoInput` directly
    state.todoInput = ''
    // Violation 2: `push` modifies the array
    state.todos.push(todo)
  })
);
```

It does not seem to care if you replace state directly like this

```
export const reducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(addTodo, (state, { todo }) => {
    // No violation
    state = initialState
  })
);
```

Doesn't this also violate strict state immutability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `strictStateImmutability` calls `Object.freeze` on `state` object. It's not going to let you change any of its properties (like you mentioned in the post) but you can replace the entire object with something else.

Take a look at this example:

```
let state = { foo: 'bar' };
Object.freeze(state);
state.foo = 'test'; // won't work
state = { foo: 'test' }; // will replace the entire object and Object.freeze doesn't matter
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej, I think I came to that same conclusion. The strange part for us is that each slice of state is a property of greater state using ActionReducerMap to put them in a subslice of a larger state. I would have thought the root state was frozen but it appears each slice is frozen. Thank you for your response. We're still going to shy away from replacing state in the reducer because of unintended side-effects.